# Java Stream - groupingBy() and counting() when a curtain Condition is met

Tags: java, java-stream, collectors, groupingby

Given the following class `Test`

```
class Test {
    String testName;
    String studName;
    String status;
}
```

and a *list* of *tests*

```
List<Test> tests = List.of(
        new Test("English",     "John", "passed"),
        new Test("English",     "Dave", "passed"),
        new Test("Science",     "Alex", "failed"),
        new Test("Science",     "Jane", "failed"),
        new Test("History",     "Dave", "passed"),
        new Test("Mathematics", "Anna", "passed"),
        new Test("Mathematics", "Lisa", "passed"),
        new Test("Mathematics", "Paul", "failed"),
        new Test("Geography",   "Mark", "passed"),
        new Test("Physics",     "John", "failed"));
```

I need to group by `testName` and count **only** where `status` equals `"passed"`. I need to do the equivalent of below code with streams :

```
Map<String, Long>  result2 = new HashMap<>();
for (Test t : tests) {
    result2.putIfAbsent(t.getTestName(), 0L);
    if (t.getStatus().equals("passed")) {
        result2.computeIfPresent(t.getTestName(), (k, v) -> v + 1);
    }
}
```

The correct and desired output:

```
{Geography=1, English=2, Science=0, Mathematics=2, History=1, Physics=0}
```

I'm looking for a stream approach, but couldn't find a solution yet. A simple `Collectors.counting` will count all, regardless of status "failed/passed":

```
Map<String, Long> resultCounting = tests.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        Test::getTestName,
        Collectors.counting()
    ));
```

*Output:*

```
{Geography=1, English=2, Science=2, Mathematics=3, History=1, Physics=1}
```

I thought about filtering beforehand, but then I will loose those subjects where all statuses are `"failed"`.

```
Map<String, Long> resultFilter = tests.stream()
    .filter(t -> t.getStatus().equals("passed"))
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        Test::getTestName,
        Collectors.counting()
    ));
```

*Output:*

```
{Geography=1, English=2, Mathematics=2, History=1}
```

How can I group **all** tests by `testName`, but count only those where status is `"passed"` ?

Is it possible to wrap `Collectors.counting()` in some kind of condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the desired result by using *collector* [`toMap(keyMapper,valueMapper,mergeFunction)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap(java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.BinaryOperator)).

`valueMapper` function would either produce `1` or `0` depending on on the `status`.

```
Map<String, Integer> passCountByTestName = tests.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        Test::getTestName,
        test -> test.getStatus().equals("passed") ? 1 : 0,
        Integer::sum
    ));
    
passCountByTestName.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + " -> " + v));
```

*Output:*

```
Geography -> 1
English -> 2
Science -> 0
Mathematics -> 2
History -> 1
Physics -> 0
```

***Sidenote:*** it would be better to use `boolean` or **enum** as type for the `status` property instead of relying on string values.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was focused in `groupingBy` that i didn't think of other collecting methods. Works perfekt. Thank you again.